# Unity: неправильный вывод в консоли

Tags: unity3d, отладка, консоль, логирование

При выводе какой-либо информации в консоли unity, используя метод debug.log, высвечивается ниже лишняя ненужная системная информация, вероятно это ошибка в unity, как это можно исправить, скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пытаюсь вывести слово "pistol", но в итоге получаю море лишней информации в виде какой-то, похоже, ошибки. Как убрать эти лишние строчки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании консоли в Unity можно отключить вывод некоторой информации, если вы хотите выводить строку, переданную в Debug.Log() без вывода состояния стэка. Нужно выбрать либо ScriptOnly - тогда состояние стэка будет выводиться только с помощью кода, либо None, чтобы не выводить системную информацию вовсе.

Это должно решить вашу проблему, если вы, конечно, в данном случае используете Debug.Log("piston").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]